# Verifying nonce from WP_List_Table

Tags: php, wordpress, nonce

I'm setting up bulk actions in a WordPress plugin using WP_List_Table. The only bulk action I want to allow is delete. I have a link to delete items that passes a nonce generated with

```
wp_create_nonce( 'deletePoll' )
```

When I click the link it works just fine. I'm verifying it in the processing code with

```
check_admin_referer( 'deletePoll' );
```

But when I use the bulk action form to try to delete I get the are you sure you want to do this? message.

I looked in wp-admin/post.php to see how they handle this with trashing items, and it seems to be exactly the same, except it works.

Answer (score 3):

why not use

`wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'bulk-' . $this->_args['plural'] ) );`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce

Comment: This is correct OGZCoder. If you're verifying a nonce an edit.php archive for a post you need to use 'posts' in place of $this->_args['plural']